# WCF Service returns null values

Tags: c#, wcf

I have few WCF servics that work fine on our test server (Windows Server 2008 R2). When i move these servics to prod server, services returns null. I am not sure what is causing this. I am guessing these is something missing on the production server but not sure what is it. Below is teh exception log. Appreciate any feedback. Thanks

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>131075</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-12T16:19:39.2467613Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="4332" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>CGWAPP268PD</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
          <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/HEIGISDataSvc-1-130234759301892473</AppDomain>
          <Exception>
            <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
            <Message>Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.</Message>
            <StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ThrowHttpProtocolException(String message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, String statusDescription)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&amp;amp; requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: Well, are the bindings for the client and the service mismatched? (ref. Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.)

Comment: open client and go to web references and update the references. Tell me if that fixed your issue.]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the key to it:

> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

[A thread on the ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1714338.aspx) deals with the same issue.

> This is usually a mismatch in the client/server bindings, where the
>   message version in the service uses SOAP 1.2 (which expects
>   application/soap+xml) and the version in the client uses SOAP 1.1
>   (which sends text/xml). WSHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.2, BasicHttpBinding
>   uses SOAP 1.1. Try the following ways to check whether it can reslove
>   your issue.
>
> 1. Change basicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding
> 2. Change your application pool to run under Network Service and gave Network Service the proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback everyone. It turns out that after setting "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true in application adv setting resolved this issue.